# Background discovery and connection : WiFi direct

Tags: android, connection, wifi-direct

Is it possible to discover and connect to nearby devices in the background using WiFi Direct?

If yes, how do I maintain those connections or how do I keep connections alive with all the devices in order to do some operation (sending text, image etc )?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the API does not pose any restrictions for background usage. You can advertise & discover from background just the same as you would do in foreground.

Basically the connection for WiFi Direct is kept just fine when app moves to background. The actual message exchange requirements are of course then solely depending on which API you are using, though, so far I have not experienced any problems in that front either.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please explain "_The actual message exchange requirements are of course then solely depending on which API you are using_"?

Comment: Basically Wifi Direct, you simply create a group, in which you know the IP address of the Group owner. Thus then if you want to exchange messages, you would need to do actual data connection, for example open a socket connection between the devices, utilizing the IP address you got with Wifi Direct API.